# Java. В Intellij IDEA все файлы классов стали файлами .java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, настройки

Все файлы классов java в Intellij IDEA, которе находятся в папке com.company стали файлами java.
До этого они определялись нормально, и компилятор мог запустить как отдельный класс, так и отделный метод из этого класса. Теперь запуск происходит только через Shift+F10 и выполняется всё по порядку с самого начала. Так же перестали выводится подсказки по автозаполнению. Не могу понять, как вернуть всё обратно. Прошу помощи.[image: На картинке файлы "EduE", "Figure", "Main", "TestFrame" - теперь выглядят так][image: Так было раньше, и я не знаю как вернуть всё в это состояние.]

Comment: На первом скриншоте: Файлы "EduE", "Figure", "Main", "TestFrame" - теперь выглядят так.
На втором скриншоте: Так было раньше, и я не знаю как вернуть всё к такому состоянию.

Comment: что выполняется всё по порядку с самого начала... как-то не понятно. напротив метода мейн будет зелёный треугольник, нажми его и выбери ран.... на счёёт автозаполнения пробуй file -> invalidate Caches-> invalidate adn restart

Comment: Спасибо, что не оставили меня с моей проблемой.
Я нечайно включил режим энергосбережения в IDE.
В этом и была проблема, уже смог выключить.