# Java. В Intellij IDEA все созданные классы стали файлами .java

Tags: java, intelij

Вопрос тот же самый, что и в вопросе [Java. В Intellij IDEA все файлы классов стали файлами .java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296969/java-%d0%92-intellij-idea-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-java#comment2287243_1296969)

[image: должно быть так]

[image: Но почему то прям создает их в таком виде]

Будьте добры помогите пожалуйста. Создает вместо файлов классов, просто java файлы, с которыми ты не можешь нормально работать, ни подсказок, ни запуска, отключение энергосбережения не помогло.

Comment: Java файлы пустые?

Comment: Нет файлы не пустые в них обычные учебные коды..

Comment: Вопрос не понятен.  Исходный код и должен содержаться в `.java` файлах, файлы классов `.class` содержат бинарный байт-код после компиляции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK -> (select java version which you want to use )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

затем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

file -> invalidate Caches-> invalidate adn restart

Если не получится ,то пробуй

1.Build->Rebuild Module
2.Build->Build Project

Если это не поможет ,то создавай новый проект , выделяй все пакеты и копируй в новый проект,скопируй туда pom.xml и все нужные дополнительные папки (папки .idea out target копирывать НЕ НАДО!)

Comment: не помогло file -> invalidate Caches-> invalidate adn restart и последнее,  1.Build->Rebuild Module 2.Build->Build Project пишет java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError